# Insert, Delete, Update table without using grid control in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005

How to insert, delete, update etc without using data grid server control in asp.net

Comment: Please see this resource on MSDN Retrieving and Modifying Data in ADO.NET it should cover pretty much every everything you'll need to know http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254937.aspx

Answer (score 0):

By using either other data controls or by using custom code (for instance in the codebehind) that accesses the database.

More cannot really be said with this very unspecific question.

Answer (score 0):

If it is the `GridView` that you dislike, use some [other data control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295567.aspx)

- [DataList control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295015.aspx)   The DataList control is useful for displaying data in any repeating structure, such as a table. The DataList control can display rows in different layouts, such as ordering them in columns or rows. For information about programming the DataList control, see DataList Class in the MSDN library.
- [DetailsView control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295027.aspx)   The DetailsView control gives you the ability to display, edit, insert, or delete a single record at a time from its associated data source. The DetailsView control displays only a single data record at a time, even if its data source exposes multiple records. For information about programming the DetailsView control, see DetailsView Class in the MSDN library.
- [FormView control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295401.aspx)   The FormView control gives you the ability to work with a single record from a data source, similar to the DetailsView control. The difference between the FormView and the DetailsView controls is that the DetailsView control uses a tabular layout where each field of the record is displayed as a row of its own. In contrast, the FormView control does not specify a pre-defined layout for displaying the record. Instead, you create a template containing controls to display individual fields from the record. For information about programming the FormView control, see FormView Class in the MSDN library.
- [Repeater control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295084.aspx)   The Repeater control is a data-bound container control that produces a list of individual items. You define the layout of individual items on a web page using templates. When the page runs, the control repeats the layout for each item in the data source. For information about programming the Repeater control, see Repeater Class in the MSDN library.

You could create simple crud forms yourself too and use `SqlCommand` to fire queries on the database.